# Rails + Passenger removing controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have picked up a legacy Rails app that uses Apache + Passenger.

The app has no documentation for me to work with.

When I run the application and hit a URL like so:

http://app.local:3000/groups/group-name

It will hit the show action in the groups controller.  However when I run the app on Apache + Passenger and hit the same URL:

http://app.local/groups/group-name

It will actually tries to load the following URL:

http://app.local/group-name

From the log it has this:

> Started GET "/groups/group-name" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-19 03:28:44
>   +0000
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/group-name"):

It is a total long shot and sorry to not provide anymore information but does anyone know why this would be happening and any suggestions of where to look?

I have checked the http.conf and it has no rewrite rules or anything.  Just a standard http.conf for Passenger + Rails.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Tony

Comment: If there are no rewrite rules, the content of `routes.rb` would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I noticed in the apache config that a python ntlm module is being used and I think that may be intefering with things.  I am going to look into that.  Thanks again.